# How to calculate percentage from one column for past X weeks of data?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table with below columns:

```
week_number     client_id       status
```

Below is what each column means:

```
week_number has values like 'W1', 'W2' ... 'W53'.
client_id has values with numbers in it.
status has two values only 'accepted' and 'rejected'.
```

Now I need to do below calcuatlion for each week and get the percentage of it for past 6 weeks (not including current week) and group by each week as well.

```
find count of 'status' column which are 'accepted' for each week.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
find count of 'status' which are both 'accepted' and 'rejected' for each week.
```

So output I need should be in this format:

```
week_number     percentage
W1               5.1%
W53              15.9%
W52              2.5%
W51              11.0%
W50              13.6%
W49              19.4%
```

Is this possible to do by any chance? I tried like this but this doesn't work and also I don't want to use `limit` clause here to get past 6 weeks data. Is there any way to do this efficiently without using any limit clause?

```
select
week_number,
((select count(status) from event_information where status in ('accepted')) / count(status)) * 100 as percentage
from event_information
group by 1
order by len(week_number) desc, week_number desc
limit 6;
```

Comment: Your week numbers are ambiguous.  How do you identify the year?

Comment: Year will be the year we are in right and basis on that calculate past 6 weeks?

Comment: Then you won't have W52 in the data.  It hasn't happened yet.

Comment: I need past 6 weeks so current week is 2 so now we can go back to past 6 week right automatically which can be 1, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49 from current week calculation? No? or I am understanding it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation like this:

```
select week_number,
       avg(case when status = 'accepted' then 100.0 else 0 end) as accepted_ratio
from event_information
group by week_number
order by week_number desc
limit 6;
```

The `100.0` is to get a value between 0 and 100.  I prefer ratios between 0 and 1 (for which I would use 1.0).

Note the "last six weeks part" is a bit string, given that you haven't mentioned a "year" column.  Based on your comment, there is a real date in the column, so you can use `order by min(client_date) desc` to get the proper ordering.

Comment: I tried this query but I got `accepted_ratio` as 0 for all the past 6 weeks. Any thoughts why?

Comment: I just realize there is a column called `client_date` in format `2021-01-18 00:00:00.0` which has date in it. Can we use this now to do this?

Comment: Any thoughts on why I get 0?

Comment: @AndyP . . . That is odd.  Postgres calculates the average of an int as a decimal; I figured Redshift did as well.  Just cast it to a numeric or float.

Comment: I tried that now but I get an error as  - `cannot cast type boolean to numeric`.

Comment: yeah I fixed that on my own after reading what it is doing. Thanks

Comment: Do you think we can use `client_date` here to get past 6 weeks if possible?

Comment: If I use `order by min(client_date) desc` then in the result it shows week starting from 53 and it doesn't show current weeks in starting.

Comment: @AndyP . . . If `client_date` is related to `week`, then it should have the same ordering.  If you don't have a date or year, you have a problem with your data.  You cannot distinguish the same date in different years.